# Call subclass methods?

Tags: java, oop, if-statement, inheritance, set

So, I have this super class:

```
public class Guest {

    private int id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private LocalDate joinDate;

    public Guest(int id, String firstName, String lastName, LocalDate joinDate){

        this.id = id;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.joinDate = joinDate;

    }
    public int getID(){ return id; }
    public String getFirstName(){ return firstName; }
    public String getLastName(){ return lastName; }
    public LocalDate getJoinDate(){ return joinDate; }
}
```

and its sub class

```
public class VIP extends Guest{

    private LocalDate VIPstartDate;
    private LocalDate VIPexpiryDate;

    public VIP(int id, String firstName, String lastName, LocalDate joinDate, LocalDate VIPstartDate, LocalDate VIPexpiryDate){

        super(id, firstName, lastName, joinDate);

        this.VIPstartDate = VIPstartDate;
        this.VIPexpiryDate = VIPexpiryDate;
    }
    public LocalDate getVIPstartDate(){ return VIPstartDate; }
    public LocalDate getVIPexpiryDate(){ return VIPexpiryDate; }
}
```

In another class, I have a list called 'guests' where all the guest information is stored.

How can I call the VIP subclass methods like this? (guests is a list where guest info is stored)

```
for (Guest guest : guests){
    guest.getid()  // so this calls from the super class - this works
    guest.getVIPstartDate() // this is meant to call from sub class - this doesn't work
}
```

^ I can't do this in my code. Why not?

How am I able to do this?

Thanks

Comment: If the objects in guests list are of type Guest then you cannot invoke getVIPStartDate on them because they are not of type VIP but are of type Guest and Guest does not have a method getVIPStartDate.
if the objects are of type VIP then you can type cast to VIP and invoke your method on vip object

Answer (score 2):

You would have to cast it first:

```
((VIP) guest).getVIPstartDate()
```

Answer (score 2):

You instantiated your Guests as the superclass. Without casting there is no way for the software to know you actually want VIP.
There's a LOT of different ways to deal with this.

As Andronicus above me mentioned, Casting is the most obvious solution. (It's also generally what similar homework assignments are looking for) BUT you need to be careful here to verify it is actually the right subclass to cast to.

```
if (guest instanceof VIP){
   ((VIP) guest).getVipStartDate();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This solution will work.

```
((VIP) guest).getVIPstartDate();
```

Comment: This is the exact repetition of my answer

Comment: i  was intitally trying to edit your answer itself but it was asking for atleast six char change fo edit,

Comment: And what's the difference?

Comment: parenthesis, you can check it by running.

Comment: @Andronicus At least for me, ((VIP) guest). works, (VIP guest). doesn't. Change your answer to that and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of example that probably help for calling subclass 'class Manager extends Employee { . . . public void setBonus(double b) { bonus = b; } private double bonus; } There is nothing special about these methods and fields. If you have a Manager object, you can simply apply the setBonus method.

Manager boss = . . .; boss.setBonus(5000);